# Deploy precompiled QtQuick qml module

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I'm using Qt6 / QML with CMake.

For my own qml files, I use `qt_add_qml_module()`. They're embedded into binary and are loaded using `qrc://` scheme, as suggested [in documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#qml-caching-for-deployment-preview).

QtQuick qml files (QtQuick.Controls, etc) are added to the distribution using macdeployqt / windeployqt tool. As far as I can tell, that tools just add qml source files and don't pre-compile them.

When I run the app, it caches lots of qmlc and jsc file in `<CACHE_DIR>/<APP_NAME>/qmlcache` (e.g. `~/.cache/MyApp/qmlcache` on Linux).

I have two questions:

1. Does `qt_add_qml_module()` automatically compile my own qml files? So the binary contains qml byte code, not qml source code?
2. Is there a way to pre-compile **QtQuick** qml files (files from qml standard library) and distribute byte code instead of source code? How can it be done using CMake?

I see that [QtQuick debian package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/qml-module-qtquick-controls/filelist) contains qmlc files, so this likely is possible, but I'm not sure how much efforts does it need to do the same using CMake and whether it would work with Qt6.

Comment: I don't understand your question #2. You should not need to distribute your QML source files if they're already embedded into your binary.

Comment: Have you read about the [Qt Quick Compiler](https://www.qt.io/blog/the-new-qtquick-compiler-technology)?

Comment: In question #2, I mean qml files of QtQuick (qml "standard library"), for example `QtQuick/Controls/Basic/Control.qml`.

Comment: So the question is about *how* to tell Qt Quick compiler to compile standard library and how to deploy the result with my app.